# List containing different types

Tags: haskell

I am currently writing my own structurewhich can handle ints and strings at the same time:

Something like

```
data Collection = One Int | Two String | Three(Collection)(Collection)
```

However, I was trying to write a function which could convert my structure into a list.

Am I right in thinking this is impossible because, by default doing:

> [1,2,"test"]

in the console doesn't work and therefore my function is bound to always fail?

Comment: This question brought to you by the vocabulary word of the day: [heterogeneous](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Heterogenous_collections).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should probably just define

```
type Collection = [Either Int String]
```

Then, instead of doing

```
l = [1,2,"test"]
```

you can do

```
l :: Collection
l = [Left 1, Left 2, Right "test"]
```

If you want more than two types, you'll need to define your own member type.  So you would do something like this aswell

```
data MemberType = MyInt Int | MyString String | MyFloat Float deriving Show
type Collection = [MemberType]
l :: Collection
l = [MyInt 1, MyInt 2, MyString "test", MyFloat 2.2]
```

The `deriving Show` isn't necessary, but it's nice to be able to simply do `print l` to print the list in a nice way.

Comment: This looks good- and this means I can recognize whether my input is an  Integer or a String?

Comment: Does using Either mean I am limited to two different types?

Comment: I've edited it to show how to use more than two types.  I'm not sure what you mean by 'recognize'.  It will not automatically know whether it's a string or int - you will have to use `MyInt` or `MyString` as in my last example.  However, it will 'remember' the type, which will be useful if you want it to treat the types differently later on.

Comment: Did you mean to say type Collection = [MemberType]?

Comment: Yes, @Dan. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 4):

Your data structure is basically a binary tree which stores either an `Int` or a `String` at each leaf. A traversal of this tree would naturally be a `[Either Int String]`.

Answer (score 2):

Lists in Haskell can only have one type. If you want a list to handle multiple types, you'll need to create a new wrapper type which can represent both of the types you want to put into it, along with functions to extract the original type and handle it. For example, you could use [`Either`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Data-Either.html).