# Haskell - how to use if then else in list comprehension?

Tags: haskell

I wish to generate a list of points from rolling two dice. If the two dice show the same value then the output points will become `(i,i,i,i)`.

My code is like

```
[(i,j)|i<-[1..6],j<-[1..6], if i==j
                            then (i,i,i,i)
                            else (i,j)]
```

When I entered this to GHCi, it cannot be compiled.

The output I expect is

```
[(1,1,1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(2,1),(2,2,2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3,3,3),(3,4),(3,5),(3,6),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3),(4,4,4,4),(4,5),(4,6),(5,1),(5,2),(5,3),(5,4),(5,5,5,5),(5,6),(6,1),(6,2),(6,3),(6,4),(6,5),(6,6,6,6)]
```

Comment: So what's the type of the output list you desire?

Comment: You've edited to address the question in the comment, but the question still remains: what is the type of the output list you desire?

Comment: I want a list of all possible combination. I am not sure what type it is since some points contains 4 Int value (i,i,i,i). I have no idea how to define the type of output list

Comment: (that comment is to check your understanding of Haskell, because Haskell is a strictly typed language, so you must be misunderstanding something.)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485726/list-containing-different-types .

Comment: Curious, why same value dice creates a 4-tuple if there are only two dice?

Comment: @karakfa I think it's for Backgammon

Comment: @Probie, yes I think you're right, the moves...

Comment: If you want equal dice to count double, that probably belongs in the interpretation of the rolls (that is, the rules of the game), not the dice rolls themselves.

Answer (score 5):

list elements should be same type, your 4-tuples and 2-tuples are not.
If you switch to list instead you can write like this

```
[if i==j then [i,i,i,i] else [i,j] | i<-[1..6], j<-[1..6]]
```

which will generate

```
[[1,1,1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[1,6],
 [2,1],[2,2,2,2],[2,3],[2,4],[2,5],[2,6],
 [3,1],[3,2],[3,3,3,3],[3,4],[3,5],[3,6],
 [4,1],[4,2],[4,3],[4,4,4,4],[4,5],[4,6],
 [5,1],[5,2],[5,3],[5,4],[5,5,5,5],[5,6],
 [6,1],[6,2],[6,3],[6,4],[6,5],[6,6,6,6]]
```